# Simple asymmetric encryption algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encryption, public-key-encryption

I want to implement simple asymmetric encryption algorithm using javascript (or reuse open library). I don't want to use RSA (or other algorithms), because they are complicated. All I want to do is illustrated in following pseudo code:

```
var encryptor = new AsymEncript();
var encrypted = encryptor.encrypt("hello world", "public key string");
var decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted, "private secret key");
```

I don't want to deal with complicated libraries such as pidCrypt, jsencrypt. I need a really simple algorithm, which allow me to create public\private key pair. Then I can use this pair for encryption.
Can you point me out to some articles or some ideas how this can be implemented?

Comment: The algorithms *are* in fact complicated, you're not going to make a "simpler" *algorithm* that easily. All you're looking for is a user friendly default wrapper function around those algorithms. Unfortunately library recommendations aren't really what we do here.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption uses invertible mathematics functions. They are complicated for strong algorithms. I need a much simpler functions. `f(x)=x*pubKey`. `x` - message, `pubKey` - public key, `f(x)` - encryption algorithm. `g(m)=m*pKey`, `g(f(x))=x`. m-encrypted message, `pKey` - private key, `g` - decryption algorithm. All I need is **simple** `f` and `g`. And I am looking for any articles regarding such functions

Comment: You could ask on crypto.stackexchange.com for an asymmetric cryptosystem that is easier to understand / implement than RSA, although I'm wondering if there are any.

Comment: JSEncrypt contributor here - What do you find complicated in the library? Taking your code and translating it to JSEncrypt will work for as soon as you use the same instance: `var encryptor = new JSEncrypt(); var encrypted = encryptor.encrypt("hello world"); var decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted);`. JSEncrypt will take care of creating a new private/public key pair if it was not set previously. (otherwise just add the line `encryptor.setKey('private key string');`

Comment: @AntonioE., thank you for your answer. I was looking for something really simple, but didn't find any suitable algorithm. JSEncrypt is good, solid and easy to use library. It fits to my needs perfectly. Currently I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your equations:
`f(x)=x*pubKey`
`g(m)=m*pKey`
`g(f(x))=x`

You arrive at this:
`x=f(x)*pKey` => `x=x*pubKey*pKey` => `pubKey = 1/pKey`

This seems like a ***very weak*** algorithm (unless I misunderstood you somehow).

If you really care about your security, you should go with some wrapper library that does `RSA` (or some other algorithm) for you in a simple manner.

Comment: You'r absolutely right, but it's just an example. I'm looking for similar functions, but they should be simpler than RSA. For my solution this would acceptable level of security, but RSA is like overhead.

Comment: @Kai IMHO, `RSA` is mathematically rather simple (just an exponent). The only 'issue' is generating the keys properly. You can find other algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Examples).  
If you want to implement your own algorithm end-to-end you'll end up doing much more work and probably end up with a weaker algorithm.

Comment: OK, it seems that using RSA with library wrapper is simpler for me. Thanks for help!